# RStudio truncates long strings when pasting into IDE - workaround?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using R 3.6.1 and RStudio 1.3.1056.

When pasting a long character string into RStudio using either `paste()` or `paste0()` or even `c()` or just simply assigning the string to an object, I get some strange results, and it looks to be unique to RStudio (if you place this code directly into R it works just fine; the correct value is given for `nchar()`):

```
thing <- paste0("(blah blah
                '100869017', '100895297', '100937037', '100952542', '100953872', '100958290', '100977291', '100978521', '100982570', '100983764', '100986439', '100987969', '100988635', '100988637', '100989748', '100992594', '100998300', '100998306', '101000068', '101000556', '101002036', '101002550', '101002813', '101002871', '101002872', '101003492', '101003787', '101003789', '101003830', '101004348', '101004349', '101004400', '101004401', '101005323', '101005738', '101006388', '101006411', '101006413', '101006414', '101006416', '101006417', '101006419', '101006440', '101006441', '101006442', '101006443', '101006444', '101006445', '101006446', '101006447', '101006448', '101006449', '101006450', '101006451', '101006452', '101006453', '101006454', '101006455', '101006456', '101006457', '101006458', '101006554', '101006588', '101006608', '101008736', '101009658', '101011518', '101011680', '101011681', '101012457', '101012495', '101014157', '101014197', '101014240', '101014244', '101014248', '101014301', '101014302', '101014303', '101014304', '101014358', '101014480', '101014481', '101015219', '101017560', '101019383', '101019396', '101019454', '101019480', '101019481', '101019567', '101020977', '101022585', '101024007', '101024436', '101028376', '101028377', '101028405', '101029814', '101030739', '101030940', '101031364', '101031368', '101032356', '101032399', '101032440', '101032441', '101032442', '101032443', '101032444', '101032462', '101032468', '101032482', '101032483', '101032484', '101032485', '101032486', '101032487', '101032488', '101032489', '101032590', '101032591', '101032735', '101032987', '101033456', '101036227', '101037275', '101038196', '101038279', '101038930', '101038932', '101038938', '101039576', '101041116', '101041233', '101041288', '101042815', '101043166', '101043280', '101043281', '101043282', '101043285', '101043288', '101043307', '101043302', '101043329', '101043405', '101043837', '101045392', '101045635', '101046419', '101046440', '101046441', '101047082', '101047224', '101047227', '101047275', '101047281', '101047286', '101047287', '101047288', '101047290', '101047293', '101047295', '101047297', '101047304', '101048355', '101048439', '101048480', '101048905', '101048921', '101050905', '101052305', '101052442', '101052448', '101052449', '101052480', '101052481', '101052485', '101052487', '101052489', '101052522', '101052550', '101052551', '101053187', '101055017', '101055036', '101055039', '101055220', '101055258', '101055313', '101055316', '101055317', '101059567', '101060256', '101060554', '101060810', '101060817', '101061738', '101061739', '101061762', '101062369', '101062469', '101063528', '101063909', '101065440', '101065471', '101065473', '101065536', '101065760', '101065784', '101065805', '101065813', '101068343', '101068346', '101069329', '101069472', '101069478', '101069771', '101069871', '101069902', '101070895', '101071301', '101071303', '101072911', '101072914', '101072915', '101072944', '101072946', '101072949', '101072972', '101072981', '101072984', '101072985', '101073389', '101073806', '101074467', '101074469', '101074650', '101074709', '101074721', '101074869', '101075639', '101075881', '101075887', '101075888', '101076841', '101076843', '101076884', '101076885', '101076889', '101076930', '101077036', '101077872', '101077877', '101078006', '101078141', '101078834', '101079626', '101079624', '101079658', '101080128', '101080146', '101080341', '101080389', '101080732', '101080738', '101080931', '101081744', '101081745', '101082123', '101082443', '101082445', '101082447', '101085919', '101086763', '101086774', '101086801', '101086915', '101086964', '101086965', '101087006', '101088057', '101088465', '101089884', '101089915', '101089945', '101090159', '101090197', '101090225', '101090226', '101090227', '101090229', '101090293', '101091218', '101091232', '101091238', '101091239', '101091635', '101091655', '101092773', '101092997', '101093029', '101093064', '101093067', '101093255', '101093344', '101097283', '101097668', '101098444', '101098514', '101099068', '101099073', '101099076', '101099141', '101099170', '101099172', '101099173', '101099175', '101099177', '101099178', '101099194', '101099204', '101099206', '101099581', '101099666', '101100002', '101100179', '101100492', '101100617', '101101080', '101101088', '101101091', '101101092', '101101115', '101101117', '101101150', '101101158', '101102050', '101102086', '101102101', '101102108', '101102169', '101102650', '101102712', '101103376', '101106299', '101106618', '101107257', '101107277', '101108114', '101108119', '101108670', '101108702', '101108707', '101109772', '101109774', '101109779', '101111022', '101111029', '101113873', '101114376', '101114390', '101115163', '101115246', '101115247', '101115357', '101115358', '101116813', '101116819', '101116870', '101116877', '101118108', '101118175', '101118178', '101118277', '101118441', '101118449', '101118471', '101118505', '101118631', '101119051', '101119448', '101119914', '101120073', '101120076', '101120127', '101120292', '101120334', '101120387', '101120389', '101122367', '101122822', '101122881', '101122886', '101124670', '101124838', '101125490', '101125610', '101126329', '101127340', '101127341', '101127342', '101127343', '101127346', '101127347', '101127360', '101127853', '101127855', '101127856', '101127857', '101128128', '101128126', '101128132', '101128135', '101130135', '101131523', '101132622', '101132648', '101132850', '101132870', '101132931', '101132938', '101132990', '101132994', '101133104', '101133206', '101133248', '101134597', '101134599', '101134611', '101134649', '101134661', '101134704', '101134771', '101135221', '101135276', '101135278', '101135409', '101135444', '101135518', '101135630', '101135633', '101135632', '101137571', '101137750', '101137812', '101137875', '101138237', '101139907', '101139931', '101139968', '101140076', '101140148', '101140181', '101140250', '101140253', '101140460', '101140462', '101140466', '101140469', '101140518', '101150986', '101150987', '101150990', '101150994', '101150995', '101151373', '101151376', '101151416', '101151418', '101151419', '101151434', '101151437', '101151891', '101151974', '101151978', '101151979', '101151996', '101152030', '101152031', '101152032', '101152037', '101152062', '101152063', '101152066', '101152068', '101152069', '101152070', '101152072', '101152073', '101152074', '101152077', '101152078', '101152080', '101152081', '101152083', '101152085', '101152087', '101152088', '101152089', '101152100', '101152103', '101152105', '101153684', '101153944', '101153966', '101153996', '101153999', '101155013', '101155141', '101155149', '101155311', '101155560', '101155880', '101155882', '101155883', '101155884', '101155905', '101156458', '101156459', '101156511', '101156524', '101156546', '101156547', '101156596', '101156611', '101156641', '101156664', '101156752', '101156786', '101156801', '101156842', '101156885', '101156888', '101156892', '101157753', '101157844', '101157881', '101157905', '101157927', '101158001', '101158011', '101158025', '101158028', '101158034', '101158061', '101158081', '101158084', '101158103', '101158107', '101159736', '101160183', '101160203', '101160234', '101160373', '101160377', '101160381', '101160378', '101160451', '101160551', '101162202', '101162245', '101162247', '101162249', '101162492', '101162538', '101162585', '101162595', '101162627', '101162630', '101162634', '101162792', '101162848', '101162876', '101162904', '101164138', '101164337', '101165132', '101165133', '101165134'
                blah blah)")
nchar(thing)
```

The output of `nchar()` is 4130. In reality, `nchar()` should be showing 7603.

Why would I do something like this in a script? In this case, it was a SQL query written into a script and being run via RStudio.

Even stranger is removing the "blah blah" at the top and bottom of the string:

```
thing <- paste0("'100869017', '100895297', '100937037', '100952542', '100953872', '100958290', '100977291', '100978521', '100982570', '100983764', '100986439', '100987969', '100988635', '100988637', '100989748', '100992594', '100998300', '100998306', '101000068', '101000556', '101002036', '101002550', '101002813', '101002871', '101002872', '101003492', '101003787', '101003789', '101003830', '101004348', '101004349', '101004400', '101004401', '101005323', '101005738', '101006388', '101006411', '101006413', '101006414', '101006416', '101006417', '101006419', '101006440', '101006441', '101006442', '101006443', '101006444', '101006445', '101006446', '101006447', '101006448', '101006449', '101006450', '101006451', '101006452', '101006453', '101006454', '101006455', '101006456', '101006457', '101006458', '101006554', '101006588', '101006608', '101008736', '101009658', '101011518', '101011680', '101011681', '101012457', '101012495', '101014157', '101014197', '101014240', '101014244', '101014248', '101014301', '101014302', '101014303', '101014304', '101014358', '101014480', '101014481', '101015219', '101017560', '101019383', '101019396', '101019454', '101019480', '101019481', '101019567', '101020977', '101022585', '101024007', '101024436', '101028376', '101028377', '101028405', '101029814', '101030739', '101030940', '101031364', '101031368', '101032356', '101032399', '101032440', '101032441', '101032442', '101032443', '101032444', '101032462', '101032468', '101032482', '101032483', '101032484', '101032485', '101032486', '101032487', '101032488', '101032489', '101032590', '101032591', '101032735', '101032987', '101033456', '101036227', '101037275', '101038196', '101038279', '101038930', '101038932', '101038938', '101039576', '101041116', '101041233', '101041288', '101042815', '101043166', '101043280', '101043281', '101043282', '101043285', '101043288', '101043307', '101043302', '101043329', '101043405', '101043837', '101045392', '101045635', '101046419', '101046440', '101046441', '101047082', '101047224', '101047227', '101047275', '101047281', '101047286', '101047287', '101047288', '101047290', '101047293', '101047295', '101047297', '101047304', '101048355', '101048439', '101048480', '101048905', '101048921', '101050905', '101052305', '101052442', '101052448', '101052449', '101052480', '101052481', '101052485', '101052487', '101052489', '101052522', '101052550', '101052551', '101053187', '101055017', '101055036', '101055039', '101055220', '101055258', '101055313', '101055316', '101055317', '101059567', '101060256', '101060554', '101060810', '101060817', '101061738', '101061739', '101061762', '101062369', '101062469', '101063528', '101063909', '101065440', '101065471', '101065473', '101065536', '101065760', '101065784', '101065805', '101065813', '101068343', '101068346', '101069329', '101069472', '101069478', '101069771', '101069871', '101069902', '101070895', '101071301', '101071303', '101072911', '101072914', '101072915', '101072944', '101072946', '101072949', '101072972', '101072981', '101072984', '101072985', '101073389', '101073806', '101074467', '101074469', '101074650', '101074709', '101074721', '101074869', '101075639', '101075881', '101075887', '101075888', '101076841', '101076843', '101076884', '101076885', '101076889', '101076930', '101077036', '101077872', '101077877', '101078006', '101078141', '101078834', '101079626', '101079624', '101079658', '101080128', '101080146', '101080341', '101080389', '101080732', '101080738', '101080931', '101081744', '101081745', '101082123', '101082443', '101082445', '101082447', '101085919', '101086763', '101086774', '101086801', '101086915', '101086964', '101086965', '101087006', '101088057', '101088465', '101089884', '101089915', '101089945', '101090159', '101090197', '101090225', '101090226', '101090227', '101090229', '101090293', '101091218', '101091232', '101091238', '101091239', '101091635', '101091655', '101092773', '101092997', '101093029', '101093064', '101093067', '101093255', '101093344', '101097283', '101097668', '101098444', '101098514', '101099068', '101099073', '101099076', '101099141', '101099170', '101099172', '101099173', '101099175', '101099177', '101099178', '101099194', '101099204', '101099206', '101099581', '101099666', '101100002', '101100179', '101100492', '101100617', '101101080', '101101088', '101101091', '101101092', '101101115', '101101117', '101101150', '101101158', '101102050', '101102086', '101102101', '101102108', '101102169', '101102650', '101102712', '101103376', '101106299', '101106618', '101107257', '101107277', '101108114', '101108119', '101108670', '101108702', '101108707', '101109772', '101109774', '101109779', '101111022', '101111029', '101113873', '101114376', '101114390', '101115163', '101115246', '101115247', '101115357', '101115358', '101116813', '101116819', '101116870', '101116877', '101118108', '101118175', '101118178', '101118277', '101118441', '101118449', '101118471', '101118505', '101118631', '101119051', '101119448', '101119914', '101120073', '101120076', '101120127', '101120292', '101120334', '101120387', '101120389', '101122367', '101122822', '101122881', '101122886', '101124670', '101124838', '101125490', '101125610', '101126329', '101127340', '101127341', '101127342', '101127343', '101127346', '101127347', '101127360', '101127853', '101127855', '101127856', '101127857', '101128128', '101128126', '101128132', '101128135', '101130135', '101131523', '101132622', '101132648', '101132850', '101132870', '101132931', '101132938', '101132990', '101132994', '101133104', '101133206', '101133248', '101134597', '101134599', '101134611', '101134649', '101134661', '101134704', '101134771', '101135221', '101135276', '101135278', '101135409', '101135444', '101135518', '101135630', '101135633', '101135632', '101137571', '101137750', '101137812', '101137875', '101138237', '101139907', '101139931', '101139968', '101140076', '101140148', '101140181', '101140250', '101140253', '101140460', '101140462', '101140466', '101140469', '101140518', '101150986', '101150987', '101150990', '101150994', '101150995', '101151373', '101151376', '101151416', '101151418', '101151419', '101151434', '101151437', '101151891', '101151974', '101151978', '101151979', '101151996', '101152030', '101152031', '101152032', '101152037', '101152062', '101152063', '101152066', '101152068', '101152069', '101152070', '101152072', '101152073', '101152074', '101152077', '101152078', '101152080', '101152081', '101152083', '101152085', '101152087', '101152088', '101152089', '101152100', '101152103', '101152105', '101153684', '101153944', '101153966', '101153996', '101153999', '101155013', '101155141', '101155149', '101155311', '101155560', '101155880', '101155882', '101155883', '101155884', '101155905', '101156458', '101156459', '101156511', '101156524', '101156546', '101156547', '101156596', '101156611', '101156641', '101156664', '101156752', '101156786', '101156801', '101156842', '101156885', '101156888', '101156892', '101157753', '101157844', '101157881', '101157905', '101157927', '101158001', '101158011', '101158025', '101158028', '101158034', '101158061', '101158081', '101158084', '101158103', '101158107', '101159736', '101160183', '101160203', '101160234', '101160373', '101160377', '101160381', '101160378', '101160451', '101160551', '101162202', '101162245', '101162247', '101162249', '101162492', '101162538', '101162585', '101162595', '101162627', '101162630', '101162634', '101162792', '101162848', '101162876', '101162904', '101164138', '101164337', '101165132', '101165133', '101165134'")
```

In this case the console hangs with the `+` as if awaiting further input.

Again, take those examples and put them directly into R and `nchar()` provides the correct count.

The worst part of this is that in the first example, the object is created but is truncated, *and the final part of the string is retained*, i.e. the ending "blah blah". This has resulted in SQL queries excluding some criteria - over 3400 characters worth of criteria!

If anyone was to say that this is an ugly way to write SQL queries, I'd agree. And I certainly wouldn't want a single string so long anywhere in my code, but there's a solid chance they could show up in a team environment where a user is less familiar with R and RStudio.
RStudio gives absolutely no indicator or warning that this is done as far as I can tell.

Is there any way to avoid this behavior besides splitting strings or sourcing SQL scripts or text files?

Comment: I'm more surprised that this works in R than I am that this doesn't work in RStudio. R has a hard coded `CONSOLE_BUFFER_SIZE` of 4095 so that should be the maximum line length. Something weird must be happening when you have a string that spans multiple lines (has a newline literal inside).

Comment: Side note that might side-step the issue: I deal with SQL every day, and I actively avoid including "data" in the query string itself. I much prefer "parameter-binding". It isn't perfect, but if your vector is `vec`, then perhaps `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, paste("select ... where id in (", paste(rep("?", length(vec)), collapse = ","), ")"), params = as.list(vec))`.

Comment: @r2evans, for sure there are cleaner ways to run queries. I generally prefer to write my query as a .sql file and run something along the lines of ```query <- readLines("my_query.sql")
q_result <- odbc::dbGetQuery(con, paste0(query, collapse = "\n"))

But working in a team environment with people who are used to SAS or STATA and who copy a string from notepad and paste it into RStudio expecting it to work and getting no indication it **didn't** work - that's problematic.

Comment: I understand, and I agree. My point is mostly about guarding against inadvertent sql-injection, and a little about allowing query optimizers to do their job. Sorry for the distraction, I see your dilemma and have nothing to offer on the char-width issue.

Comment: @r2evans, I getcha. No problem. Thanks!